# Pi 3 reboots when GPIO 13 is given 3V

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, reboot

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdigxI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am taking the 3V from Pi and giving it to COM of a relay.
The NO goes to GPIO 13 of the same Pi.

I have a 120V line that triggers the relay, which then connects the 3V to GPIO 13.

It was working fine for a couple of days.
However, suddenly its rebooting everytime the relay triggers and connects the 3V to GPIO 13.

This happened when I was doing something else and my code to open GPIO 13 for input was not even executed. Can it be because of that?
I am not explicitly setting the GPIO 13 to output, its in the default state after reboot (which I believe is Input)

I dont have immediate access to the Pi as its at a remote location. So I haven't been able to try it with some other pins yet.

Can this be a magnetic field issue when the relay gets triggered?

Comment: What do you mean by give 3V?  You can't power the Pi via the GPIO.  Do you mean you are using the GPIO to test if the relay is on or not?

Comment: Yes, in a nutshell, I'm checking if the relay is ON or not. I'm using it as a signal, which is detected in my code, then I act on it

Comment: As long as it is no more than 3V3 then that is fine.  That should not have caused a problem.

Comment: You might want to elaborate about how it is getting those 3 volts.  Also, if at any point that pin is set as an *output set low* you are potentially sourcing too much current (unless an appropriate resistor is being used).

Comment: @goldilocks, My first statement says I'm giving Pi its own 3v on GPIO 13. Not sure what you want me to elaborate. I'm not setting the pin as an output, because it happens even when I dont run any script. From what I read, default on reboot is Input

Comment: The terms you use are not clear, and what you're trying to accomplish even less so. I appreciate that we might have a wee language barrier, but unless your meaning is unequivocal, we may inadvertently advise something that you would implement and damage or destroy your RPi. Have you noticed that there is a schematic tool available? Please use it to draw a diagram; this will reduce confusion significantly.

Comment: @Seamus, I didnt know that, I'll give it a try. But its just 3v of Pi going back to its own GPIO. And that line is controlled by a Relay. Thats it

Comment: @DushyantBangal: Thanks for the diagram. And it seems to have paid off as Milliways has prepared an answer. Try his suggestions, and if they don't clear things up, post here with a new diagram and code snippets if you can. The only other thing that might be useful to know is the spec on your relay - or a part number. Do let us know how you get on; I'm confident this is a soluble problem :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about GPIO13 (including all 3 possible interpretations of the pin) which would cause the Pi to reboot, although the absence of any code leaves this indefinite.

The circuit however is poor design.

1. You should always use a small series resistor (to prevent problems
   if the GPIO is configured as  output).
2. The input "floats" - you should use a pullup (or in the listed
   circuit a pulldown) - while the default has a pulldown this is very
   high impedance.
3. There is no filtering or debounce - debounce can be done in
   software, but a hardware solution is needed to minimise interference.

Without detail of the wiring - in particular the physical layout/length it is possible the circuit would be subject to interference; at a minimum you should use low impedance terminations to minimise this.

A final point, naive users seem to assume that a pin should be connected to HIGH to trigger - most professional circuitry would connect between GPIO and GND; with CMOS circuitry there is no technical difference in performance, but running 3.3V supply over long external cabling is dangerous, and subjects the whole circuitry to additional risk of shorts/interference.

Comment: All this happened even before I executed my code. I need the thing to work normally if my code does not start. So the GPIO is in the default state. I have put debounce in my code, but like I said, the issue occurs even before I execute it.

Comment: Are you saying that I should use GND instead of 3.3v? Will it trigger the GPIO.RISING event?